# How can we prompt with some tag?

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I was wondering if you can help me with some sample.

I know that modules like tag and when are helpful on this case. However, I am having hard times to create the yml file.

*The goal is:*
*On server1, the commands are:*

```
 /bin/startJob
/bin/stopJob
/bin/validateJob
```

*On server2, the commands are:*

```
/bin/startTask
/bin/stopTask
/bin/validateTask
```

I would like to prompt to the user the option on what he would like to do. For example:

```
ansible-playbook services.yml
```

*The playbook says:*

> Services available for Server1:
>
> A. /bin/startJob
>
> B. /bin/stopJob
>
> C. /bin/validateJob
>
> Services available for Server2:
>
> D. /bin/startTask
>
> E. /bin/stopTask
>
> F. /bin/validateTask

The user type letter E, and the ansible-playbook runs the command /bin/stopTask from the Server2.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 playbooks: `start`, `stop` and `validate`, 2 inventories: `server1` and `server2` with variables defining specific command names for given env.

Users would just call: `ansible-playbook -i server2 start.yml`

Comment: It’s a good idea. But image a server with 10 commands. Now imagine 10 serves with different commands. It will become a problem to manage all of them. To solve the problem of multiple servers, would you create one inventory and one yml with tags and when?

Comment: If you have multiple servers where the same commands are called differently then group the same servers in inventory files and set the command names in variables for those groups. Here's how: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables

There's no need for tags just create a separate playbook for every command type as I expect nobody will want to run more than one command at a time.